# What CTAF/phraseology should be used for non-airfield departures?

Tags: radio-communications

Assume a pilot has landed their aircraft on a body of water in a lightly populated area, though the question still holds for large grassy meadow. The time has come for them to depart.

They're not on an airfield, per se, but there are airfields in the area at various distances and of various degrees of business.

While I'm sure it's perfectly legal to simply get airborne and go blasting into the sky... As a matter of safety and courtesy: on what frequency and using what phrasing should the pilot announce their departure and intentions in case someone else is contemplating an approach to the same site they're departing from?

If specifics are required, assume the pilot is flying an ICON A5 out from Lake Keowee in Salem, SC.

Comment: I'd lean toward using the CTAF at LQK (122.8) or CEU (119.27). Especially CEU if you'd be operating on the sourthern portion of the lake within CEU's Class-E-at-700'AGL circle.

Comment: "Lake Keowee traffic, ICON A5 taking off to the North, Lake Keowee..."

Comment: @randomhead The flight I'll be simming this evening involves overflying the Oconnee Nuke so that's a good thing for me to keep in mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you’re talking about a lake or a body of water, or a off field landing site commonly used by aircraft, but not identified as an land or water airport or helipad as such on aeronautical charts and publications.  In these situations, it would be good practice to use the MULTICOM frequency of 122.9 to announce your position and intentions as prescribed in AIM 4-1-9.  Pilots approaching or egressing from such areas may use the air-to-air frequency 122.75 or 123.05 (for helicopters).  Groups of aircraft entering or egressing here areas may also communicate on ‘fingers’ frequency of 123.45 as well.

Organizations like the Seaplane Pilot’s Association also publish commonly used procedures and information on popular water destination for seaplanes.